# Number pad is not working

Tags: 64-bit, 13.10

After new installation of Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, I face there is problem in my keypad. I face my keypad is not working. then I realize that it functioning but it behave like a mouse pointer. I can see there is no effect of number led on / off. I can see number led change its states but not my number key pad.

Comment: Does the mouse move, when you press one of the numbers 14789632? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/362971/edit) and add the information.

Answer (score 1):

Is the mouse moving when you press one of the numbers 14789632 ?

If so, check this setting: *System Settings >> Universal Access >> Pointing and Clicking tab >> Mouse Keys*.

If it says *On*, click it to change it to *Off*.

Comment: This worked for my Ubuntu 14.04. Somehow some application changed the setting and all of a sudden the numpad was no longer working.